# How is Entity Framework 4's POCO support compared to NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

Just wondering if anyone has had any experience using Entity Framework 4's POCO support and how it stands up compared to NHibernate. If they're the same, I'd be very interested in making Entity Framework 4 my ORM of choice if only because it would:

1. Support both data first AND object first development
2. Have a robust LINQ provider
3. Be easier to pitch to clients (since it's developed by Microsoft)
4. Come baked into the .NET framework rather than requiring 8 dlls to get up and running

**In other words, are there any major shortcomings to EF4?**

Does it support all of the basic functionality NHibernate supports (lazy-loading, eager-loading, 1st level caching, etc.) or is it still rough around the edges? Is the syntax for setting up the mappings as easy as NHibernate and/or Fluent NHibernate?

Edit: Please don't bring up the vote of no confidence. That was ages ago and dealt with some serious shortcomings of EF1 that really don't seem to apply anymore to EF4.

Comment: As far as I know, NHibernate supports data first development.  On the other side, it may be a while before some clients adopt VS2010/.NET 4.

Comment: Technically, yes. NHibernate supports data first development in that it doesn't actively prohibit you from doing it. However, it's clear that NHibernate's suggested path is to do code-first development while EF4 seems to give equal weight to both approaches. For instance, EF4 can take an existing legacy database and quickly generate classes to be used for data access. With NHibernate, you'd have to do that all by hand which is incredibly time-consuming.

Comment: What are these 8 dlls you are talking about? It's only like 4 or so :) and you only need to reference 2 of em...NH and the bytecode provider I thinks...

Comment: There are a whole bunch of code generators for NHibernate, so I'm not sure why you would not do the same thing with NHibernate that you do with Entity Framework. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752/nhibernate-generators

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Ayende has a pretty detailed [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx) comparing the two, although he admits it's not a thorough point-by-point breakdown (which is kind of what I was hoping for here).

In general, I think the points he brings up in favor of NHibernate are valid, albeit a bit on the "nice to have" side. If this is really where EF4 is currently lacking, it sounds like EF4 is a great alternative to NHibernate if only for the reasons I listed in the original question.